# HTC One won't play any video after update

Tags: updates, video, htc-one, video-streaming

My Android HTC One is currently running Android Version 4.4.2, a few days ago it updated a bunch of apps, about 27 I think. I honestly can't remember which updated and which didn't.

Since then it won't play any videos. It won't play any video files from my memory card and it won't play any videos from YouTube, Facebook etc...!

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>Screenshot (click for larger variant)</sup>

A similar error pops up for every application.

Has anyone else encountered this issue?

Comment: I've got what I think is the same issue with my Nexus 4. I can't pin down exactly when it happened, but it's likely to be around the latest OS update. On YouTube I get "connection to server lost \n Touch to retry" but I can still successfully chrome cast the same video. Does that describe your problems? (I don't want to create a duplicate question)

Comment: @Mike My problem was across every video player on my HTC One, chrome cast, youtube and even the the playback feature for videos I had recorded myself. Different errors for each piece of software but none of them worked. I took Husman's advice and went over the list of apps I had updated and for the in the comment section of the youtube app, there were several comments from people with the same issue I had. It seems as if the youtube app was behind it, (but no one was too sure). I just restarted my phone and the issue seemed to resolve itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to the play store and view the 'my apps' section. This should list your most recently updated apps. You can check the top 27 or so and see if it helps you determine, which one may be affecting video playback.

Comment: ah cheers Husman! I'll chk that out asap.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using a third party video player of your device,say, VLC Media Player, then go to setings>Apps>Manage Apps>VLC>Clear Data, and reset the data.
Once done, use a system cleaner app like Cleaner Master and clear the Junk on your device. This should solve he problem.

If the problem still persists, opt to reinstall the video player app.

Comment: Cheers for the reply Kanishk but I haven't installed any third party video player. As far as I now, it's still using the video player that came with it.

Answer (score 0):

Turn your phone on and off it worked for me